# hacer videollamadas de whatsapp desktop en linux ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Buenas a toda la comunidad: tengo desde hace 2 años un portátil con ubuntu 22.10 y tengo descargada la aplicación de whatsapp y no consigo hacer video llamadas, por lo tanto, necesitaría, me dijeran que pasos o bien por comandos o bien por entorno gráfico habría que seguir

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugerimos revisar [ask], agrega lo que trataste o investigaste.